# Looking to upgrade Qliksense from May 2021 to August 2022 version

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

We have previously installed Qliksense May 2021 version.
We want to upgrade Qliksense from May 2021 version to August 2022 version. Database which we are using is postgres database.

Scenario 1: If we try following process, will our Qliksense application get successfully upgraded to August 2022 version along with august configuration(metadata) and may 2021 database
or will it show inconsistent behaviour, like may 2021 version with both Configuration(metadata) and worked data of May 2021 version on August 2022 version?

- Take the backup of existing Qliksense May 2021 Qliksense application.
- Uninstall Qliksense may 2021 version.
- Install Qliksense August 2022 version.
- Restore May 2021 version backup data.

Scenario 2: Or if we try following process, will our Qliksense application get successfully upgraded to August 2022 version along with august configuration(metadata) and may 2021 database.

- Install (Override) the Qliksense August 2022 version on installed (running) May 2021 version.

Will both scenario will be good fit? If not which one will be good fit?

We expect smooth upgrade from May 2021 to August 2022 Qliksense version

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to ask Qlik Support about this.

That being said ...

In my experience we are performing an upgrade (Scenario 2). We dont want to loose and re-create all other configurations (QMC) if we uninstall and install.

Before each upgrade we are taking a [backup](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-admin/February2023/Subsystems/DeployAdministerQSE/Content/Sense_DeployAdminister/QSEoW/Deploy_QSEoW/Backup-and-restore.htm) of the database and the certificates.

Regarding the apps. As far as i know Qlik will not automatically upgrade the apps to the latest version (during the upgrade). After the upgrade all apps will be in not migrated status (or migration status is unknown) in QMC. When select such an app (in QMC) there will be a new button at the bottom `Migrate`.
You can manually trigger migration for all apps this way.

OR

next time the app is opened/accessed the Engine will automatically upgrade it. [Here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2023/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/CreatingAppLoadingData/CreateApps/migrate-app.htm) is a doc that explains the background process.